# The same function gets fired repetedly on button click after dynamic changing the class of the function?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am trying to make a function in "js" that can change/replaces the attribute-value of a given element. But I am facing a problem of the same function getting triggered after changing the button class dynamically which should trigger another function on the click this time.

My code:

```
<p>Hello world</p>
<button class="top2">Change Size</button>
<script>
    //Note:- function "data_exists" check if a data exists in the array or string;
   // And add_attr adds an attribute or values to a existing attr
    
    function eventlisten(elem, eventType, func) {
        if(document.contains(elem)){
           elem.addEventListener(eventType, func);
        }
    }

    // Fired when the button.top2 is clicked [1st function]
    eventlisten(document.querySelector('button.top2'), 'click', function(){
        let p = document.querySelector('p'); // gets the p element
        add_attrs(p, {'class': 'size'}, true); // adds the attr
        changeAttrValue(document.querySelector('button.top2'), 'class', 'top2', 'undo_size'); // Changes the button class to 'undo_size'
    });

    // Fired when the button.undo_size is clicked [2nd function]
    eventlisten(document.querySelector('button.undo_size'), 'click', function(){
        let p = document.querySelector('p.size');// gets the p element
        add_attrs(p, {'class': 'top3'}, true);// adds the attr
        changeAttrValue(elem=document.querySelector('button.undo_size'), attr='class', oldAttr='undo_size', newAttr='top2'); // Changes the button class to 'top2'
    });
    
</script>
```

After clicking the button.top2 the elements look:

```
<p class="size">Hello world</p>
<button class="undo_size">Change Size</button>
```

The first function works fine but this time when the button is pressed the first function is fired again instead of the second function

What should I do to prevent the trigger of the first function where the second function should be fired.

Thanks in advance to all those ho read my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.querySelector('button.top2')
```

returns a reference to the `button`, that happens to have the class `top2` at that moment. `addEventListener` then attaches the event listener to that specific element. It doesn't know/care that you happend to originaly refer to that element with the class.

```
document.querySelector('button.undo_size')
```

returns (when called in your script at that point) always `null`. There is no `button` with the class `undo_size` at that point, and it doesn't care that there might be one in the future.

I guess that is way you created the (basically pointless) function `eventlisten`, because you get an error when trying to call `addEventListener` on `null`. `if (document.contains(elem))` in your case is just a different way to check `if (elem !== null)`, because `document.contains(null)` always returns `false`.

There probably is a way to switch event handlers, but it's probably easier, just to have one event handler and check which class is set. Something like this:

```
eventlisten(document.querySelector('button.top2'), 'click', function(){
        let p = document.querySelector('p'); // gets the p element
 
        // `this` in the event handler refers to the button that was clicked on
        if (this.classList.contains('undo_size')) {
            add_attrs(p, {'class': 'top3'}, true);// adds the attr
            changeAttrValue(this, 'class', 'undo_size', 'top2'); // Changes the button class to 'top2'
        } else {
            add_attrs(p, {'class': 'size'}, true); // adds the attr
            changeAttrValue(this, 'class', 'top2', 'undo_size'); // Changes the button class to 'undo_size'
        }
    });
```

BTW, the assignments (`elem=`, `attr=`, etc.) in the last line don't make much sense. JavaScript doesn't have named parameters, if that is what you are going for).

Comment: Thanks, The code finally worked. Well yes that is what I was going for. I am new to js so still learning about it. I was confused so I did that. BTW, I want to know that if I add new elements dynamically,(like getting the data from server), do I need to add the js part in the response or add it with the main script. If yes, how will I make that work?

Comment: Better post a new question for that, but look up "event delegation". You can attach events not only directly to the element you are interested in, but also to a parent element (e.g. the `body`) and then inside the event handler check which element was actually clicked.